# How to create a PDF that is editable in the browser?

Tags: pdf, browser, adobe, edit, xfa

I stumbled upon a curious feature on a hosted PDF document, you can download a slice of the pdf [here](https://jmp.sh/s/7PYDqbJOQsWkDCdoJCSl). Notice the buttons at the bottom, the red one cleans the page, and the blue one prints the document.

Here's a section of the PDF that has editable lines:

[image: text edit on PDF]

This document allows users to edit text directly within the browser. Not only can you type, but there are also some action buttons for clearing the page and printing the file. Overall it enables users to make changes to the document without needing any external software besides the browser (Chrome and Firefox).

What kind of technology is being used for this? How could I create such a PDF with editable text and action buttons?

Thank you!

Comment: I've just noticed I can edit it on Adobe Acrobat. It is not protected.

Comment: And it shows this message @KJ: _"The author of this form has specified the fields which you can fill. Click on any field to start editing."_.

Comment: I can save it with my data. It is supposed to do so because it is a public template for a composition.

Comment: The producer is: Adobe PDF Library 20.13.96.

Comment: PDF Version 1.6

Comment: Ohhh... so if I wanted to create a custom PDF like that I'd have to purchase a license, right? For Adobe Acrobat?? I'm sorry I'm not used to these tools

Comment: I can replicate (by copying and editing) the owner's PDF but it is inflexible for what I wanted: create those editing boxes and action buttons. I found it really intriguing and never expected a PDF would be able to do so.

Comment: But it's not something urgent, meaning I found it cool, but I don't plan to get a license just for it.

Comment: I'm almost sure it doesn't have a server, it seems JS in PDF.

Comment: you can download a slice of the pdf here: https://jmp.sh/s/7PYDqbJOQsWkDCdoJCSl

Notice the buttons at the bottom

Comment: That's basically what you've shared. But I wonder what's the API for making those buttons. Curiously it seems that the PDF is turning into a web app.

Comment: Wow!! Great to know. It's valuable information

Comment: I'll take a look at it tomorrow, but thank you SO much for pinpointing this information. Bye for now

Comment: Yeah, that's true. But I wanted to understand how to make custom-sized boxes and action buttons without proprietary files.